# Derived data type

Tags: c++, types

Why is an array called a derived data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the base datatypes provide u to store more than 1 value [ Eg : int, char, float etc ]
An array is nothing but, an extended form of the base data type, holding N items of the base data type. So, due to this, array is called the derived data type.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that they are derived from the fundamental data types. (Actually, the [version of the standard I looked up](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) puts them under **Compound types**.)

Comment: A perfect answer to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

The term does not appear in the C++ Standard, as far as i can determine. Where did you read it?

Answer (score 1):

C provides us with mainly five generic/primary data types, 
Here are the types & their ranges.

- char      -128 to 127 - any ascii characters includes alphanumerics & special characters
- int       -32768 to +32767 - only numbers/integers
- float     3.4 e-38 to 3.4 e+38
- double    1.7 e-308 to 1.7 e+308
- void      notapplicable

In case, if any of the above are not sufficient for representing any type for your problem, C has provided us with compound types like struct where you can defined your own types.

For eg: 
Fractions.
To represent Fraction we need two integers, one for the numerator & second for the denominator.

So, we define a strcuture like below

```
typedef struct {
      int numer;
      int denom;
} fraction;
```

And from now, we can start using fraction to declare any new variable.
fraction, here is a user-defined data type also referred some times as derived data type.

I am not aware that arrays are also referred as data types.
To my knowledge, Array is a collection of finite number of elements of same data type, where each element is accessed by an index ranging from 0 to n-1, where n is no. of elements in the array.

With this defintion, I am not sure whether Arrays can be classified as derived data types.
Like you, I am also waiting for a reason if at all they are classifed as derived data types.

Answer (score 0):

- it is comprised of other datatypes.
- [An array name is really a pointer to the first element of the array](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/arrayptr/26arraysaspointers.html) ,, [and the pointer is a derived data type ..](http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/cplusplus/Csyntax-files/pointers.html)

http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071229234805AAyuACh